# Sorting the Bars in Chart.JS Bar Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have been recently experimenting with ChartJS and have come into a problem regarding sorting the bars in descending order, from lowest to highest. I have tried to debug but found no luck.

Comment: is there any error message? What does it show?

Comment: hi, no this problem has been solved, however, I am looking for help in another issue. I would really really appreciate if you could help me on this issue. Thanks a million. I havent been able to get proper assistance on it.

Comment: Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487777/updating-html-graph-with-mysql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the "beforeupdate" is called when you click the "Sort Data" button, because it seems you use the wrong variable.

```
barChart → barGraph
```

**UPDATED**
The old one [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dfyLu90n/)
**UPDATED**
[Here is the link](https://jsfiddle.net/fay4ej89/)

```
// Get the data from each datasets.
var dataArray = [];
$.each(chart.data.datasets, function() {
    dataArray.push(this.data);
});
// Get the index after sorted.
let dataIndexes = dataArray.map((d, i) => i);
dataIndexes.sort((a, b) => {
    return dataArray[a] - dataArray[b];
});
// create after sorted datasets.
var tempDatasets = [];
$.each(dataIndexes, function() {
    tempDatasets.push(chart.data.datasets[this]);
});
// apply it
chart.data.datasets = tempDatasets;
```

***What data is returned using Ajax?***

```
data = [{
    sample : "ALPINE",
    electric : 100,
    mpg: 200,
    urban: 300,
    vmt: 400,
    airtravel: 500,
    renewable: 100,
    conservation : 200,
    heating: 300,
    water: 400,
    cefficiency: 500,
    shiftc: 100,
    healthyd: 200
}];
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. so you copied and pasted, right? but you changed the data structure, there's no way that code working. That sort logic (your sort logic) only works if the data is gathered in one array. like this. However, do you want to implement the picture you uploaded? I'm not sure how it works. Why is the left label just one?

Comment: Yes, I want to implement the picture I uploaded, I want it to the same thing that the JS Fiddle is doing, where on clicking sort, all the bars will be sorted. Do you know how I can do this. It would really help. If you can modify the code for it to work, that would seriously help a lot. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Since I also copied it, I don't quite understand the logic of getting a sort index, but I got it how to sort datasets. I edit my answer.

Comment: HiThanks so much for your help. However, the one problem is that im not getting my data from the database. So was my earlier code wrong in doing that. If you have any help on doing sorting functionality from the data in the database, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you want clearly. What is the problem? Once you create a bar graph, where the data came from is nothing to do with this sort logic. If you mean that you can get the sorted data from the database(using order by), you just destroy and re-create a bar graph.

Comment: so your saying that the code which you gave in JS Fiddle for the sort logic should work when I apply it to my previous code. But when I apply it to my code, its not working properly even with the new sort logic code that you gave. Can you apply the sort logic code to the very original code that I had pasted above, so I can see how its supposed to really work. THanks for all your help!

Comment: I apply it your original code, but I change the ajax's URL to avoid error. Also, I don't get the data using ajax, so I set it manually. if the data structure is wrong what I thought, this code won't work.check 75 rows in the js fiddle. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jznL3m92/1/)

Comment: yeah thats the thing, I need to get it via ajax, because my original graph pulls data from the database, so I cant set it manually.

Comment: I didn't use ajax, because I don't have an API, but you are using ajax to call your own code(localhost), so why don't you just return the correct format data?

Comment: OK, final question. The fact is that I can successfully both jsfiddle which are I wrote my answer. So it seems you use a different data structure from me. Please show me your data structure editing your question, just like I did.

Comment: ok, i updated the question with the new and modified code using the new sorting code i got from your js fiddle. Can you check yo see wats wrong. Yes, im pulling data from a database which is why i need to use ajax, thats my different data structure. But anyways, there is the edited code.

Comment: if you can, can you just copy paste my code into a js fiddle with a modifier, but if you can check for any wrong things with the datastructures. No output needs to be received but still so I can copy paste it to my IDE, without going back and forth. THANKS SO MUCH!!!!!

Comment: That's what that is?!, your variable "barChart" is declared in the wrong scope. you need to declare in advance, for example, putting "var barChart;" to at the under of "const CHART". And you need to rid of "var" from "var barchart = new Chart(CHART, {", like "barchart = new Chart(CHART, {".

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU SO MUCH, THANK YOU

Comment: Really!?, I thought you can use a debugging tool which the browsers have, because you used "console.log", but not?. So now, let's accept my answer:)!