# Updating HTML Graph with MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, textbox

Here is the Before Picture:dfasdfasdfasdf

Comment: Try using the POST method in your form, you can then put the input of the city in a variable: `$city = $_POST['City']` (you will achieve the same with GET, but POST is cleaner and safer

Comment: When submitting your form, the data will be parsed by the URL. (keep in mind to use GET in this example to understand). A GET value you can get by using `$_GET[]`, the city input has the name attribute 'City', so the GET statement will be $_GET['City']. try to echo $_GET['City'] or just <?php print_r( $_GET[] ); ?> to print all your data from the form

Comment: check sample: https://imgur.com/a/HwN6mj8